# Qt aplication in Visual Studio - entry point

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

I have a console application in Qt, which I would like to execute in Visual Studio, so I can use it's profiler.

I'm using a plugin called Qt VS Tool, which seems to have imported the project correctly. I can also create a new Qt project and it works fine.

However on this application that I imported, VS seems to be searching for a WinMain function as entry point instead of main, even if the "SubSystem" is set to `Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)` in **Configuration Properties -> Linker -> System -> SubSystem**.

I am getting this error:

> LNK2019   unresolved external symbol WinMain referenced in function
>   __tmainCRTStartup

If I manually change the entry point to "main", in **Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Advanced -> Entry Point**, the application starts, but `argc` and `argv` contain trash. It seems that is [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13921924/how-do-i-access-arguments-for-a-new-main-function-in-c) to pass arguments when specifying an entry point.

How can I make it work properly with `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` ?

I'm using VS 2015 Community with MSVC 11 compiler (VS 2012) due to a library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found is to set the entry point to `mainCRTStartup` in **Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Advanced -> Entry Point**. The difference between `main` and `mainCRTStartup` is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22934206/what-is-the-difference-between-main-and-maincrtstartup).

Doing that, the arguments are passed correctly to the main function.